# insert an array item in the input box on changing the combo box

Tags: javascript

i want a particular array item to set as the value of input tag, when the combo1 box's selection changes.

```
    <%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*;" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
    <html>
        <head>
        </head>
    <script language="javascript">

    function check()
        {
            if(!validate())
                return false;
        }

    function validate()
        {
            if (document.form.amount.value <=0)
            {
                alert ("Please enter valid loan amount.");
                return false;
            }
            else
                return true;
        }

        var arr = new Array();
        arr[0] = new Array("-select-", "10.0","10.5", "12.0");

        function change(combo1) {
            document.getElementById("rate").style.visibility = "visible";
            var sel = document.getElementById("combo1");
        var val = document.getElementById("rate").value;
        for(var i = 0, j = sel.options.length; i < j; ++i) {
            if(sel.options[i].innerHTML == val) {
               sel.selectedIndex = i;
               break;
            }
        }
    }

}
    </script>
        <jsp:include page="include.jsp"></jsp:include>

        <body>
            <br>
            <form action="PaymentServlet.do" name="form" method="post"
                ONSUBMIT="return check()">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>
                        <font style="font-family: sans-serif" size="4px" color="Megenta">Online Loan
                            Application Page</font>
                    </legend>
                    <br />

                    Loan Type
                    <select name="combo1" onchange="change(this);">
                        <option value="0">
                            -Select-
                        </option>
                        <option value="1">
                            Home Loan
                        </option>
                        <option value="2">
                            Education Loan
                        </option>
                        <option value="3">
                            Car Loan
                        </option>
                    </select>
                    <br />

                    Interest Rate(%)<input type="text" name="rate" style="visibility: hidden;">
                    <br />
                    Loan Amount
                    <input type="text" name="loanamount" />
                    <br />
                    <input type="submit" name="go" value="o Go o" />
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

depending on the loan type i want to select the respective interest rate from the array and want this array item to be used as the value of the input tag whose name="rate".

Comment: and what is your problem?

Comment: user @ mr.VVoo unable to get the value of array in the input tag's value.

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of a combo box you need to do the following:

```
var val = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
```

`sel` is your combo box

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `document.getElementById("elementid")` by giving name as paramater. The paramater must be `id` of element not name.

Actually you don't need to use document.getElementById because you are returning `this` as paramater in change function. `this` refers the actual element.

So your change function should be like this,

```
function change(combo1) {
       document.getElementById("rate").style.visibility = "visible";
       document.getElementById("rate").value = arr[combo1.selectedIndex];
}
```

Your array definition is wrong as well. The right one is here,

```
var arr = new Array();
arr[0] = new Array("-select-", "10.0","10.5", "12.0");
```

```
var arr = new Array("-select-", "10.0","10.5", "12.0");
```

Finally don't forget to add id attribute for rate input,

```
<input type="text" id="rate" name="rate" style="visibility: hidden;">
```

And here is the complete code and a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VfHP4/1/)

```
<script language="javascript">

function check()
    {
        if(!validate())
            return false;
    }

function validate()
    {
        if (document.form.amount.value <=0)
        {
            alert ("Please enter valid loan amount.");
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }

    var arr = new Array("-select-", "10.0","10.5", "12.0");

    function change(combo1) {
        document.getElementById("rate").style.visibility = "visible";
       document.getElementById("rate").value = arr[combo1.selectedIndex];
}

</script>
    <body>
        <br>
        <form action="PaymentServlet.do" name="form" method="post"
            ONSUBMIT="return check()">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>
                    <font style="font-family: sans-serif" size="4px" color="Megenta">Online Loan
                        Application Page</font>
                </legend>
                <br />

                Loan Type
                <select name="combo1" onchange="change(this);">
                    <option value="0">
                        -Select-
                    </option>
                    <option value="1">
                        Home Loan
                    </option>
                    <option value="2">
                        Education Loan
                    </option>
                    <option value="3">
                        Car Loan
                    </option>
                </select>
                <br />

                Interest Rate(%)<input type="text" id="rate" name="rate" style="visibility: hidden;">
                <br />
                Loan Amount
                <input type="text" name="loanamount" />
                <br />
                <input type="submit" name="go" value="o Go o" />
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

if your array definition is like

```
arr[0] = new Array("-select-", "10.0","10.5", "12.0");
```

then

```
function change(combo1) {
    document.getElementById("rate").style.visibility = "visible";
    var rate = document.getElementById("rate");
    rate.value = arr[0][combo1.selectedIndex];
}
```